# Prevent CSS to wrap nodes below their max-width in a tree like mind map when there's a lot of content on the left side

Tags: css

Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/VincentBlouin/pen/zVJbaR

You can see that the nodes at the left like "1.2 left" start to wrap but they should only do so at their ".child-label" max-width:500px. I don't know why but most importantly, how to prevent it. If you remove some of the long lorem ipsum text (it's contenteditable) you'll see that the left bubbles like "1.2" get back their normal shape.

The code uses Vue.js, Vuetify.js and Material Design because it's easier for me but I think the problem is more related to flex css.

Thank you.

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify)
let Child = {
  name:'child',
  props: ["child", "direction"],
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0,
      isLeft: null
    }
  },
  mounted:function(){
    this.isLeft = this.direction === "left";
  },
  template: '#child-template'
};    
   
let tree = new Vue({
  el: '#tree',
  components:{
    'child': Child
  },
  data: {  
    root : {
    label: 'center',
      isRoot: true,
      leftChildren:[
        {
          label:'1 left',
          children:[
            {
              label: '1.1 left'
            },
            {
              label:'1.2 left',
              children: [{
                label: '1.2.1 left',
                children:[{
                  label:'1.2.1.1 left'
                },
                {
                  label:'1.2.1.2 left',
                  children:[{
                    label:"left 1.2.1.2.1 At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus"
                  ,children:[{
                    label:"1.2.1.2.1.0 left"
                  },{
                    label:"1.2.1.2.1.1 left At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus",
                    children:[{
                      label:'1.2.1.2.1.1.1 left At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus'
                    },{
                      label: '1.2.1.2.1.1.2 left'
                    }]
                  },{
                    label:'1.2.1.2.1.2 left'
                  },{
                    label:'1.2.1.2.1.3 left'
                  }]}]
                },
                {
                  label:'1.2.1.3 left'
                }]
              }]
            },{
              label:'1.3 left'
            }]
       }],
      children:[
        {
          label:'1 right'
        },
        {
          label:'2 right',
          children:[
            {
              label:"2.1 right"
            },
            {
              label:"2.2 right little bit larger"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#tree {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child-label{
  max-width:500px;
}


.vh-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

 .v-center {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.16/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.16/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="tree" class="vh-center">
  <v-layout row class="vh-center ma-5 pa-5">
    <v-flex grow class="left-branch">
      <v-layout row class="vh-center" v-for="child in root.leftChildren">
        <v-flex grow>
          <Child :child="child" direction="left"></Child>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex grow class="vh-center">
      <Child :child="root" direction="center"></Child>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex grow class="right-branch">
      <v-layout v-for="child in root.children">
        <v-flex grow>
          <Child :child="child" direction="right"></Child>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="child-template">
  <v-layout row class='child-container'>
    <v-flex class="flex-child-container" :class="{
            'v-center': !child.isRoot,
            'vh-center' : child.isRoot
            }">
      <v-spacer v-if="isLeft"></v-spacer>
      <div>
        <child :child="grandChild" :direction="direction" v-for="grandChild in child.children" v-if="isLeft && child.children && !child.isRoot"></child>
      </div>
      <div :class="{
             'vh-center':child.isRoot,                                                                        'v-center' :!child.isRoot,
             'left':!isLeft && !child.isRoot,
             'pl-2': 'isLeft',
             'pr-2': '!isLeft',
             'left':!isLeft && !child.isRoot
             }">
        <div class="child">
          <div contenteditable="true" class="pt-1 pb-1 child-label" :class="{'font-weight-bold':child.isRoot}">
            {{child.label}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <child :child="grandChild" :diection="direction" v-for="grandChild in child.children" v-if="!isLeft && child.children && !child.isRoot"></child>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get exactly what you need, but I assume you don't want the text "1.2.1.2 left" to break in two lines. Try to apply "white-space: nowrap" to them and see if it helps (:

Comment: Exactly but when I use white-space:nowrap; to class .child-label for example, I lose the effect of wrapping at max-width:500px and it looks messy.

Comment: Ok I added `flex-shrink:0;` to `.child` and it worked. Thank you Marcelo and I wasn't aware of this property.